# Adding quotation mark to a string

Tags: javascript

The title might be misleading, But i'm fairly new to JavaScript and the quotation marks is already killing me.

While page is loaded, I'm trying to add an edit button to the view and alert the random number when clicked, Like this:

```
 var docid = OSZVMeFDJ0eNaCNMffDTji5cf2I3 // random string 
 $("#tableUser").append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="loadUser('+ docid +')"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i> Edit User</button>');
```

And:

```
function loadUser(id) {
   console.log(id);
        alert(id);
}
```

But this code neither prints, or alerts. Is it because it doesn't have quotation marks? isn't the function parameters could be anything from an Integer to String?

### Update

turns out i had put `onlick()` into the `i` which means the edit icon, now i removed & added it to the button but getting this on the console:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: OSZVMeFDJ0eNaCNMffDTji5cf2I3

Comment: Can you create a minimal demo that reproduces your problem (see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)? Also, read the "*[mcve]*" and "*[ask]*" guidelines.

Comment: If it neither prints nor alerts it's not being called. As to why, can't help yet.

Comment: thank you so much @DaveNewton, i was putting the onlick in the `i` variable, Could you also look at my updated question?

Comment: You probably need double quotes around your `docId`, but be aware to escape them correctly or use escaped single quotes like that: `loadUser(\'' + docId + '\'">)`

Comment: If docId can be anything but numbers then it should be quoted.

Comment: How can i ? please edit your answer :)

Comment: @DaveNewton that's exactly my question i'm coming from mobile programming and this was never a problem :D

Comment: You already been asked to, provide a [mcve] that reproduce the issue you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `OSZVMeFDJ0eNaCNMffDTji5cf2I3` isn't a string. JavaScript sees that and assume it's a variable. The way to fix your issue is by simply wrapping those characters in double `"` or single `'` quotes - then JavaScript will recognize the string.

```js
//The function we will call when the button is clicked.
function loadUser(id) {
  console.log(`docid is: ${id}`);
}

//Add the event listener
document.querySelector('#docIdBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  //Notice how the string is wrapped in quotation marks
  var docid = "OSZVMeFDJ0eNaCNMffDTji5cf2I3";
  //Call the function you defined above, pass in the "id" arg.
  loadUser(docid);
});
```

```html
<button id="docIdBtn">Click</button>
```

Reading regarding [String syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Syntax).

Comment: How do i do this inside the onlick function?

Comment: I updated the code to and attached a click handler to the button. Now when it's clicked it will execute `loadUser`. Let me know if you need any other explanation.

Answer (score 1):

OSZVMeFDJ0eNaCNMffDTji5cf2I3 is not a string it should be 'OSZVMeFDJ0eNaCNMffDTji5cf2I3'. Java script behaves with OSZVMeFDJ0eNaCNMffDTji5cf2I3 as a variable name and sees that it is undefined.

Comment: How do i do this inside the onlick function?

Comment: I think  var docid = " 'OSZVMeFDJ0eNaCNMffDTji5cf2I3' " would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this with new ES6 feature called template literals or ticks.

```
 $("#tableUser").append(`<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="loadUser(${docid})"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i> Edit User</button>`);
```

Comment: How do i do this inside the onlick function?

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'. Expected ')' to end an argument list.` that didn't work

Comment: it will work .. you may have copy pasted it. let me create a js fiddle

Comment: anyway i'm pretty sure .. you are making syntax error now. Your loadUser wont be defined. Because you are attaching it later. User scripts operates in isolated world and  onclick operated in target page scope and cannot see your script function. so, add event listener to that edit and and try this again .. copy above code. Don't forget to use quotations on your string otherwise it will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
var docid = OSZVMeFDJ0eNaCNMffDTji5cf2I3
```

should be

```
var docid = "OSZVMeFDJ0eNaCNMffDTji5cf2I3"
```

Otherwise you are trying to use OSZVMeFDJ0eNaCNMffDTji5cf2I3 as a variable, which does not exist.

If you are learning JavaScript programming from scratch, a few other pointers:

1. Don't use var. Use const or let, depending if it's a constant or a variable.
2. Avoid jQuery. It was a good library, a decade ago. With today's JavaScript is unnecessary and will hinder your learning. Specially when you jump to any of todays frameworks and libraries.
3. Use template strings, `with this quotes`. You can then interpolate any variable with ${variable}.

   `loadUser(${docid})`

Comment: How do i do this inside the onlick function?

Comment: $("#tableUser").append(\`<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="loadUser(${docid})"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i> Edit User</button>`);

Comment: Did you change the declaration of docid?

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the `<tr><td>` in your string in order to create valid HTML

**EDIT**

You have to put quotes around `docId` as it is a string not a number

Comment: Sorry just removed that :)

Comment: And is `tableUser` an HTML table element?